# Pass a pickle buffer from Node to Python

Tags: python, node.js, pickle

I have a Node application that subscribes to JSON data streams. I would like to extend this to subscribe to Python pickle data streams (I am willing to drop or convert non primitive types). The node-pickle & jpickle packages have failed me. I now wish to write my own Python script to convert pickles to JSON.

I fiddled with the node-pickle source code to get part of it to work (can pass JSON from Node to Python and get back a pickle string, can also use a predefined Python dict and pass to Node as JSON). My problem is getting Python to recognize the data from Node as pickled data. I am passing the data stream buffer from Node to Python and trying desparately to get the string buffer argument into a format for me to `pickle.loads` it.

After much trial and error I have ended up with this:

**main.js**

```js
const pickle = require('node-pickle');
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect(`amqp://${usr}:${pwd}@${url}`, (err, conn) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  conn.createChannel((err, ch) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    ch.assertExchange(ex, 'fanout', { durable: false });
    ch.assertQueue('', {}, (err, q) => {
      ch.bindQueue(q.queue, ex, '');
      console.log('consuming');
      ch.consume(q.queue, msg => {
        console.log('Received [x]');
        const p = msg.content.toString('base64');
        pickle.loads(p).then(r => console.log('Res:', r));
        // conn.close();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**index.js** (node-pickle)

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
  Bluebird = require('bluebird');

module.exports.loads = function loads(pickle) {
  return new Bluebird((resolve, reject) => {
    const convert = spawn('python', [__dirname + '/convert.py', '--loads']),
      stdout_buffer = [];

    convert.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      stdout_buffer.push(data);
    });

    convert.on('exit', function(code) {
      const data = stdout_buffer.join('');
      // console.log('buffer toString', stdout_buffer[0] ? stdout_buffer[0].toString() : null);
      if (data == -1) {
        resolve(false);
      } else {
        let result;
        try {
          result = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('failed parse');
          result = false;
        }
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
    convert.stdin.write(pickle);
    convert.stdin.end();
  });
};
```

**convert.py** (node-pickle)

```py
import sys
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle

import codecs
import jsonpickle

def main(argv):
    try:
        if argv[0] == '--loads':
            buffer = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
            decoded = codecs.decode(buffer, 'base64')
            d = pickle.loads(decoded, encoding='latin1')
            j = jsonpickle.encode(d,False)
            sys.stdout.write(j)
        elif argv[0] == '--dumps':
            d = json.loads(argv[1])
            p = pickle.dumps(d)
            sys.stdout.write(str(p))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ' + str(e))
        sys.stdout.write('-1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The error I come up against at the moment is:

> invalid load key, '\xef'

**EDIT 1**:
I am now sending the buffer string representation, instead of the buffer, to Python. I then use stdin to read it in as bytes. I started writing the bytes object to a file to compare to the data received from Node, to the buffer received when I subscribe to the data stream from a Python script. I have found that they seem to be identical, apart from certain `\x..` sequences found when subscribing from Python, being represented as `\xef\xbf\xbd` when subscribing from Node. I assume this has something to do with string encoding?? Some examples of the misrepresented sequences are: `\x80` (this is the first sequence after the `b'`; however `\x80` does appear elsewhere), `\xe3`, and `\x85`.

**EDIT 2**:
I have now encoded the string I'm sending to Python as base64, then, in Python, decoding the stdin buffer using `codecs.decode`. The buffer I'm writing to the file now looks more identical to the Python only stream, with no more `\xef\xbf\xbd` substitutions. However, I now come up against this error:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Also, I found a slight difference when trying to match the last 1000 characters of each stream. The is a section in the Python stream (`\x0c,'\x023`) that looks like this (`\x0c,\'\x023`) in the stream from Node. Not sure how much that'll affect things.

**EDIT 3** (Success!):
After searching up my new error, I found the last piece of this encoding puzzle. Since I was working in Python 3, and the pickle came from Python 2.x, I needed to specify the encoding for `pickle.loads` as `bytes` or `latin1`(the one I needed). I was then able to make use of the wonderful jsonpickle package to do the work of JSON serializing the dict, changing datetime objects into date strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to get the node-pickle npm package to work. My flow of getting a buffer of pickled data from Node to Python to get back JSON is:

In Node

- Encode the buffer as a base64 string
- Send the string to the Python child process as a stdin input, not an argument

In Python

- Read in the buffer from stdin as bytes
- Use `codecs` to decode it from base64
- If using Python 3, specify `bytes` or `latin1` encoding for `pickle.loads`
- Use `jsonpickle` to serialize python objects in JSON

In Node

- Collect the buffer from stdout and `JSON.parse` it